# PHP writes null to JSON file

Tags: php, json

I've seen similar posts to this question but I can't seem to figure it out. I have a small PHP script that reads and writes form input to a JSON file, like this –

```
  $file = 'data.json';

  $arr_data = array();

  $formdata = array(
        'name' => strip_tags( trim($_POST['formName']) ),
        'email' => $email,
        'phone' => strip_tags( trim($_POST['formPhone']) ),
        'message' => strip_tags( trim($_POST['formMessage']) )
        // also tested this just using reg strings
  );

  $jsondata = file_get_contents($file);

  //var_dump($jsondata); returns whatever string content is in the file, so seems to work

  $arr_data = json_decode($jsondata, true);

  array_push($arr_data, $formdata);

  //var_dump($arr_data); returns NULL, not sure what happens here

  $jsondata = json_encode($arr_data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

  file_put_contents($file, $jsondata);
```

Any ideas? Using PHP 5.5.9, checked that files are writeable. Both files have UTF8 encoding.

Comment: provide Your `data.json` file

Comment: Try using `var_dump($arr_data)` immediately after `$arr_data = json_decode($jsondata, true)`. Also, make sure you can see any errors. Place this at the top of your script ~ `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 'On');`

Comment: My data.json file is just blank. Should there be some pretext content in order for it to work?

Comment: yes, incase it's blank, make `$arr_data = array()` or preset the json file to `[]`

Comment: instead of array_push() use array_merge() function to append one array to another without comparing their keys.

Comment: Thanks Phil. The dump gave me "null", and using the error reporting says 
 Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in index.php on line 38 NULL. So I'm missing something in the array_push()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`json_decode()` will return `NULL` if the input is blank. Try this to ensure your `$arr_data` is an array...

```
$arr_data = json_decode($jsondata, true);
if ($arr_data === null) {
    $arr_data = [];
}
```

Comment: Wonderful! That did it :) And always good to learn something new.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you want this code

```
<?php
  $file = 'data.json';
  $email='your mail info';
  $arr_data = array();

  $formdata = array(
        'name' => strip_tags( trim($_POST['formName']) ),
        'email' => $email,
        'phone' => strip_tags( trim($_POST['formPhone']) ),
        'message' => strip_tags( trim($_POST['formMessage']) )
        // also tested this just using reg strings
  );

  $jsondata = file_get_contents($file);

  //var_dump($jsondata); returns whatever string content is in the file, so seems to work

  $arr_data = json_decode($jsondata, true);

  // I added for if data.json is null to empty array
  $arr_data = is_null($arr_data)?array():$arr_data;

  array_push($arr_data, $formdata);

  //var_dump($arr_data); returns NULL, not sure what happens here

  $jsondata = json_encode($arr_data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

  file_put_contents($file, $jsondata);
?>
```

#### others

you should change your code to keep post data not null or default values and pay attention to **file_get_contents** method about file length